# How to demonstrate Benford's Law using Mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, code-request

I tried to use Mathematica to demonstrate [Benford's law](https://www.statisticshowto.com/benfords-law/). My problem may be with my understanding of the law. The code below shows how many times each digit from 1 through 9 is the leading digit in all integers from 2 to 10^7.

```
firstDigits=First[IntegerDigits[#]]&/@Range[2,10^7];
Counts[firstDigits]
(* <| 2->1111111,3->1111111,4->1111111,5->1111111,6->1111111,
      7->1111111,8->1111111,9->1111111,1->1111111 |> *)
```

Above we see that 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 are each the leading digit exactly the same number of times. However, Benford's law says approximately 30.1% of the time the leading digit is 1.  How can we use Mathematica to illustrate Benford's Law?

Comment: Benford's law is not about just any old random collection of numbers (including the collection of *all* numbers, for which *clearly* each numbers shows up the same number of times as the leading digit). Benford's Law is about collections of numbers *used* for something, like the collection of telephone numbers, or house numbers, etc. If you read the page linked, it talks about Benford's law holding for *data sets*.

Comment: AFAIR, scale invariance is an assumption for Benford's Law. E.g., `firstDigits = First@First[RealDigits[#]] & /@ Exp@Range[-100., 100.];
Counts[firstDigits]/201. // KeySort`

Comment: You get a better approximation the closer you get to covering the positive reals at a fixed finite precision. `RealDigits` is slow, so here's a faster approach: `firstDigits = 10^(# - UnitStep[#] + 1 &@ FractionalPart@Log10@Exp@Subdivide[-5000.`24, 5000.`24, 2^20]) // IntegerPart;
Counts[firstDigits]/N@Length@firstDigits // KeySort`

Comment: There are examples on the Wolfram Demonstrations site.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BenfordDistribution.html

Comment: @Michael E2, What is ARAIR?

Comment: As Far As I Recall. I think there's an explanation (of Benford's law) in Knuth's Art of Comp. Prog. which I read back in the 80s. I could be misremembering, though.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an example using the population of all U.S. cities:

```
(* first get list of U.S. cities *)
cData = CityData[{All, "UnitedStates"}];
totalCities=Length@cData
(*32734 *)



(* retrieve population data from the city list *)
pVal = (QuantityMagnitude@CityData[#, "Population"]) & /@ cData;
firstDigits = First[IntegerDigits[#]] & /@ pVal;
(* tally the first digits in the list *)
tVals = Tally[firstDigits]
(* check the percentage of first digits that are 1 *)
oneDigits = Position[tVals, x_List /; x[[1]] == 1][[1, 1]]
oneCount = tVals[[oneDigits, 2]]
(* compute percent of  population that begins with digit 1*)
oneCount/totalCities // N
(* compare to the expected value *)
digitProb[n_] := Log[1 + 1/n]/Log[10];
digitProb[1] // N


(*0.302804*)

(* 0.30103*)
```